# Start a chrome extension without browser action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I'm wondering if there's a way to start the extension without user clicking the browser action or after the user has checked a button that enables it to start automatically. I read about the Background and Event pages in the documentation,but they don't seem to fit my purpose because they are about keeping the pages alive when the extension is already started. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The event page is started when Chrome starts. Having a browser action is optional. If you need to do something only on initial startup, use the [chrome.runtime.onStartup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup) event.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions start when the user has the browser running and the rules are matched. You can either have:

1. A background page that starts running in the background as soon as the browser is started.
2. A content script that starts running at every page load that matches your rules, ie: a regex that matches certain type of url).

You can learn more at: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted